# Am I going to die of Cancer from Asbestos if not handled correct? What more should I do?

Tags: drywall, ceiling, asbestos, old-work

So I have scrapped down old pop corn ceiling and removed staple on tile on drywall attached to plaster, that can be only lord knows how old.

I didn't hang any barriers up as we are planning to do the ceiling walls and floors in all the rooms, although I did cover up outlets and vents.

I have already removed and made the mess and got dust everywhere.

Was wearing a mask enough?

So if this stuff was everywhere (metal, wood, insulation, wall, compounds) for about 90 years. So wouldn't everyone alive in those years be dead?

Is there more I should have done? What do you normally do and why?

Comment: Lawyers and  greedy people is probably the reason for all the hype about asbestos. I know it is a bad thing, and bad things have happened because it. I have worked on houses with asbestos over the years. and thank God, I am 59 years old and smoked from 17 to 54 years old, and to date no complications from any of it, although I know in years to come that may change.

Comment: @Jack So, basically keep the amsk on finish the job clean up EXTRA EXTRA good and move on with life, if in 20-50 years it haunts me deal with it then? I can live with that.

Comment: Lawyers have made so there are laws to have specialists in asbestos removal and disposal necessary. So I cannot recommend that is what you do. In my early days of handling asbestos before it was banned, I was your age then, and on rare occasion, I get concerned over what I have been exposed to over the years, which has been a lot, but long and short of it, I don't let it run my life.

Comment: I can't take the time to answer with proper citations right now, but I have looked into this.  I have removed vinyl floor tiles with asbestos and also a few ceiling tiles, so I researched it, like you are doing, and decided the following:  Most all people who get mesothelioma from asbestos were exposed to it in high concentrations for long periods of time (in an industrial or work setting). The most dangerous type of asbestos is in insulation, not in other common products. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Related:  I have found that a good half face respirator is invaluable.  I like the 3M 6000 series with the pink P100 filters.   I wear mine every time I expect any kind of dust, no matter how little. A full face respirator is even better to have.

Comment: Simple answer to your main concern is Yes, you are going to die. If you die from asbestos contact is unlikely, but we all are going to die eventually.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about carcinogens and medical conditions, not about home improvement.  If you're concerned about your health, you should seek the advice of a medical professional.

Comment: @Tester101 I did contemplate not asking this question, but I read through the website asking rules, and they are pretty vague, I come from stackoverflow and have a fair rep on that site, and understand the working of stackexchange fairly well, But I also know that they want questions that will drive visit to the site and I felt this was a great fit to a DIY website as it is something most DIYers will probably look up at some point. I was hoping more for an actual answer, with references from experienced pro's, who can say they have worked with it a lot, and there results and any precautions.

Comment: @Tester101: I don't think this is an off-topic question. Lots of questions on this site have to do with the safety implications of various DIY work. The question is a little rambling but that doesn't make it OT.

Comment: @HenryJackson while the answer may be helpful to DIYers, a DIYer is likely not the best source for the answer.

Comment: @Tester101 I have edited the question in hopes of making it more site appropriate.

Comment: Don't smoke. Most of the people I've know who developed cancer from working around Asbestos smoked. Also, in Western Oregon, short fiber asbestos is in the soil, especially if you live near serpentine and erionite is widely dispersed in the Cascades and a broad band either side where volcanic ash has been eroded and washed downstream. Eroinite is even worse at causing mesothelioma than Asbestos is. And it's in the dust everywhere... Not just in your house.

Comment: @user2140261 The problem here, is that even cancer experts don't know exactly how cancer works. You could breath a tiny bit of asbestos and get cancer, or breath a large amount and not get cancer. The only thing that's known for sure, is that if you've breathed asbestos over a long period of time, you're *more likely* to develop cancer.

Comment: @Tester101 At this point I have to 100% disagree with you, This question is about DIY safety, Its the same as asking if I should wear eye protection or gloves or a welding shield. I am not asking what happens if I don't, I am just asking what standards and regulations if any should be followed. Not what health problems I will have. As is this is a great question for anyone looking to do work on an old house if properly answered.

Comment: @user2140261 "*Am I going to die of Cancer from Asbestos*". Sounds like you're asking what happens if you aren't properly protected.  Maybe it's poorly written, or I'm just dense.  In it's current state, this is not a useful question.

Comment: OP I understand what you're asking and I think your question is entirely appropriate. I think @Edwin advice is right on...buy a $50-60 respirator and wear it. I have done two small jobs with little respiratory protection and frankly I regret it. The first was replacing my water heater exhaust flu, which was rust rotted, and probably sealed in to the chimney vent with an asbestos product. I wore a bandanna around my nose and mouth. The second was removing the PAINTED popcorn ceiling in my old bathroom. I wore a blue mask...it was worthless. It's worth the peace of mind to have the respirator.

Comment: Ahh...I should probably add that I'm not ill or infirmed due to my brief exposure. However, from what I gather, asbestos exposure becomes an issue 20-30 years later...if it even becomes an issue. Steve McQueen died of it. But he was in the navy, removing asbestos without a mask, and experienced tremendous exposure over a few years. My hope (as I expect yours is) is that a light exposure isn't consequential. In the future, though, I will be wearing a respirator.